# Происхождение слова "елка"

Tags: этимология

Слова, начинающиеся на букву Е, для русского языка не характерны. Откуда же тогда взялось слово "ель", "елка"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Общеславянское – jedlъ (острый, колючий).
Слово является исконным и широко используется в русском языке примерно с XI в.
По мнению исследователей, в слове прослеживается древняя индоевропейская основа «edh-1-os», где корень «edh» означал «острый, колючий». Слова с тем же значением и схожим звучанием встречаются и в других славянских языках. Например, в украинском это «iль», а в болгарском – «ела».
Кроме того, слова с похожим значением и написанием встречаются в таких языках, как литовский (egle – «ель»), латышский (egle), латинский (ebulus – «бузина»).
Производные: елка, елочный, еловый.

Comment: >Например, в украинском это «iль»

В украинском это "ялина". Если ель.

А если если "ёлка", то "ялинка". Новогодняя ёлка -- *новорiчна ялинка*. 

:-) Сейчас уже полно такого товара в виде искусственных ёлочек в супермаркетах. Жители Украины каждый день на магазинных ярлыках могут читать подобную надпись.

Comment: Не могло быть такой основы в ПИЕ.

Answer (score 0):

Это комментарий.

> to [@Соан](/users/169/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%BD) Например, в украинском это «iль»

Полагаю, что это снова цитата из словаря Семенова.Допускаю,что у него были какие-то ныне забытые основания назвать ЕЛЬ по-украински именно так. На самом деле современный украинский язык может назвать ЕЛЬ "смерека"(по-польски "smerk",по-чешски "smrk")  или "ялына","ялынка".

Comment: >современный украинский язык может назвать ЕЛЬ "смерека"(по-польски "smerk",по-чешски "smrk") или "ялына","ялынка"

*Смерека* -- это только на Западной Украине говорят. 

По чешски забавно :-) *SMRK* -- ни одной гласной буквы!

Comment: В чешском,словацком некоторых других языках роль слогообразующих выполняют длящиеся согласные, например vlk (волк), smrt(смерть)и т.п.
 СМЕРЕКА - вполне литературное украинское слово, безусловно, западнославянского происхождения.СМРИКА по-болгарски и македонски означает можжевельник, тоже нечто колючее